# Why does this cause svn tree conflict?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'd like to merge one branch into another but keep getting tree conflicts in odd places.

I have the following to branches:

```
mainline
- foldera
- folderb
- folderc

mainline_ongoing
- foldera
- folderb
- folderc
```

mainline_ongoing starts off as a copy of mainline.  Then some changes are made in:

```
mainline_ongoing
- foldera\suba
```

where suba is a new folder with files.

When I try to svn merge (via Tortoise), from mainline to mainline_ongoing, i get a tree conflict on folder suba.

Why does that happen?

My goal is take merge changes from mainline (which will be small) into mainline_ongoing.  Mainlineongoing will contain lots of changes but mainly in the foldera.

Comment: Was suba directory added only in the mainline_ongoing branch?

Comment: Yes - it was added after the copy was created.